# coding 2D game physics in javascript, not-flat ground and rotation

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics

I have a small project in my webprogramming course where I am supposed to make a small game in javascript. This is the game: two cannons are fixed on
opposing ends of the game space. The cannons take turns shooting at each other, and the player tilts the cannon to some degree and chooses a force to shoot the cannonball with. There's a bunch of other stuff I'm thinking of that will be added if there's time.

I found a nice site, http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/, to get me going with 2d physics and I've made some tests, see the code below. I do however have two big problems:

1. Non-flat floor/ground.
2. Rotation!

Right now the script is only checking for the style.top value of the floorDiv, so the box will always "land" on this row of pixels. If I want to have 
variable-height terrain, this won't suffice. Any ideas from you guys on how this could be accomplished? Is there anyway to check the color at a specific pixel? If so I could check for non-sky or ground colored pixels and make this the landing critera.

I need to rotate the cannon so players can adjust their aim! I'm thinking I'll make two different cannon objects, the cannon "base" and the cannon barrel. Then I could just rotate the cannon barrel when the player presses a key. Unfortunately rotation seems to be hard in webprogramming. I found this jquery plugin, at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/, but I'm not getting it to work quite as I would like. Even though I've made sure the cannonball is centered in the picture there is also some translation, not just rotation.
I suppose this might be because the picture doesn't rotate about it's center? See the rotation test code below (you'll have to download
the rotation plugin if you want to try the code).
I suppose I could just make a picture for each angle but that seems kind of wasteful
since there's no actual visual change to the cannon otherwise.

Also, if I want to animate several objects at the same time, do you think I should just change all the objects in the same gameloop function?
Any ideas on this?

The following is the code for the physics-testing

CSS-file

```
#moveDiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000;
}

#floorDiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:800px;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#2E2;
}

table {
text-align:right;

}
table input {
    width:35px;
}
```

HTML-file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//global vars
var gravity = 0.5;
var friction = 0.5;
var moving = false;
var moveDiv;
var floorDiv;
var yPos;
var xPos;
var floorPos;
var velocity_y = 0;
var velocity_x = 0;
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize();">
<input type="button" value="fall" onclick="fall();"></button>
<input type="button" value="Push" onclick="push();"></button>
<input type="button" value="reset" onclick="reset();"></button>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Angle: <input type="text" value="45" id="angle" /></td>
<td>Speed: <input type="text" value="10" id="speed"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gravity: <input type="text" value="0.5" id="gravity" /></td>
<td>Friction: <input type="text" value="0.5" id="friction" /></td>
</table>

<div id="moveDiv"></div>
<div id="floorDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

js-file

```
function initialize() {
    moveDiv = document.getElementById('moveDiv');
    floorDiv = document.getElementById('floorDiv'); 

    moveDiv.style.left=400;
    moveDiv.style.top=50;

    floorDiv.style.left=200;
    floorDiv.style.top=400;
}//end initialize

function fall() 
{
    moving=true;
    var angle = 275;
    var rad = angle / (Math.pi * 2);
    var scale_x = Math.cos(rad);
    var scale_y = Math.sin(rad);

    var moveDivSpeed = 0;

    gameLoop();

}//end fall

function push() 
{
    moving=true;
    var angle = document.getElementById('angle').value;
    var rad = angle / (Math.PI * 2);
    var scale_x = Math.cos(rad);
    var scale_y = Math.sin(rad);
    var moveDivSpeed = document.getElementById('speed').value;
    friction = document.getElementById('friction').value;
    gravity = document.getElementById('gravity').value;
    velocity_x = moveDivSpeed*scale_x;
    console.log("original velocity_x is " + velocity_x);
    velocity_y = moveDivSpeed*scale_y;
    gameLoop();
}

function gameLoop () {
    //console.log("gameLoop start");
    var len = moveDiv.style.top.length;
    var presentTop = parseInt(moveDiv.style.top.substr(0, len-2));

    var lenX = moveDiv.style.left.length;
    var presentLeft = parseInt(moveDiv.style.left.substr(0, lenX-2));

    var len2 = floorDiv.style.top.length;
    var floorTop = parseInt(floorDiv.style.top.substr(0, len2-2));

    if (moving == true) 
    {
        velocity_y -= gravity;

        if ((presentTop+100) - velocity_y < floorTop) 
        { //if moveDiv hasn't hit the floor yet...
            moveDiv.style.top = presentTop - velocity_y;
            moveDiv.style.left = presentLeft + velocity_x;
        }
        else if (presentTop + 100 == floorTop) //if moveDiv is ON the floor
        {
            velocity_x = velocity_x*(1-friction);
            moveDiv.style.left = presentLeft + velocity_x;
            console.log("on the floor");
            console.log("friction is " + friction);
            console.log(" and velocity_x is " + velocity_x);
            console.log("moveDiv.style.left is " +moveDiv.style.left);

            if (velocity_x <= 1)
            {
                console.log("stopped moving");
                moving = false;
            }

        }
        else //if moveDiv will hit the floor/go through the floor this time
        {
            var diff = floorTop - (presentTop + 100);
            moveDiv.style.top = presentTop + diff;
            moveDiv.style.left = presentLeft + velocity_x;
        }
    }
    else if (moving == false) 
    {
        clearTimeout(runAgain);
        console.log("else if moving == false");
        return false;
    }

    var runAgain = setTimeout("gameLoop()", 5);
    //console.log("end of gameLoop");
    return false;
}//end gameLoop

function reset () {
    moving = false;

    moveDiv.style.left=400;
    moveDiv.style.top=50;

    floorDiv.style.left=200;
    floorDiv.style.top=400;
}//end reset
```

Code for the rotation-test(just the html file and the rotation plugin)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rotate.1-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#hide").click(function() {
            $("p").hide(500);
            $(".box").animate({height:300, opacity:0}, 1000);
        });

        $("#show").click(function() {
            $("p").show(500);
            $(".box").animate({height:100, opacity:100}, 1000);
        });

        $(".box").mouseenter(function() {
            $(".box").animate({height:300, opacity:0}, 500);
        });

        $(".box").mouseleave(function() {
            $(".box").animate({height:100, opacity:10}, 1000);
        });

        $("#move").click(function() {
            $("#grey").animate({left: -300, top: -100}, 1000)
            .animate({left: -600, top: 200}, 1000);
        });

        $("#cannonball").click(function() {
            $("#cannonball").animate({"left": "+=300", "top": "-=100"}, 500)
            .animate({"left": "+=300", "top": "+=100"}, 500);

        });

        $("p.fading").css("opacity","0.3");
        $("p.fading").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, "slow");}, 
                function () {
                $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.3}, "slow");
            });

        $("#rotateRight").click(function() {
            $("#cannonball").rotate(10);
        });

    }); //end jquery document.ready scripts

function initialize () {
    document.getElementById('box').style.top = 250;
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.box {
    background-color: #000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:300px;
}

.divMove {
    position:relative;
    top:350px;
    float:right;
    background-color: #ddd;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-right:100px;
}   

#cannonball {
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
<p>Let's make this disappear and appear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="move">Move</button>
<button id="rotateRight">Rotate+</button>

<div id="box" class="box">
</div>


<div class="divMove" id="grey">
</div>

<img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18833130/Webprogrammering/test/cannonball.png" id="cannonball" border="1" />
<p class="fading">This is a paragraph that fades. Let's see how it looks.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I apologize for the long post and the amount of code, but if you want to try it you can basically just copy-paste, and I thought it would be easier to discuss this way!

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/ it's a breeze for collaborating on forums such as this one.

Comment: Sounds pretty cool, thanks for the tip.

Comment: This sounds just like Pocket Tanks, but in a browser! That'd be cool.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking I'll make two different cannon objects, the cannon "base" and the cannon barrel. Then I could just rotate the cannon barrel when the player presses a key. Unfortunately rotation seems to be hard in webprogramming.

The easiest (now) would be to use the [CSS `transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

```js
const angleInputElement = document.getElementById('angle');
const degrees = angleInputElement.value;
const barrelElement = document.getElementById('barrel'); // I don't see this in your sample though
barrelElement.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
```

> Also, if I want to animate several objects at the same time, do you think I should just change all the objects in the same gameloop function? Any ideas on this?

For this simple implementation that should work fine.